# how to link to other classes

Tags: java, android

I have a lot of methods in one class, which elements refer to 1 XML Layout File. How to put these methods in extra Classes?

So I want to put this code for example:

```
public void recordSound(){  
    // abgerunderter Rahmen für den Medienplayer wird in einer TextView
    // angezeigt
    TextView soundUmrandung = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.soundumrandungtextview);

    // das Design (abgerundeter Rahmen) für den Medienplayer laden
    Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.soundshape);

    // das geladene Design auf der TextView anwenden, damit ein abgerunter
    // Rahmen erscheint
    soundUmrandung.setBackground(drawable);


    ImageButton record = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.sound);
    ImageButton recordStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.soundstop);
```

and

```
public void builtButtonsRigtLeftPic() {

    ImageButton arrowLeft = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.arrowLeft);
    ImageButton arrowRight = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.arrowRight);
    arrowLeft.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    arrowRight.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
    Drawable leftgrey = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrowleftgrey);
    Drawable rightgrey = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrowrightgrey);
```

which elements refers to the same layoutFile into different classes.

I tried it with

```
LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    final View openprojectView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.openproject, null);
```

to set the LayoutResource and call the new class by using intent (like `Intent soundRecord = new Intent(this, SoundRecord.class);startActivity(soundRecord);`, but this result in the error:

```
07-20 21:19:00.590: E/AndroidRuntime(20296): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.unitnode/com.unitnode.SoundRecord}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #88: Error inflating class fragment
```

Now I have tried it this way in new class:

> @Override
>       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.openproject);
    LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    openprojectView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.openproject, null);
    //TextView sound = (TextView) openprojectView.findViewById(R.id.soundumrandungtextview);
    //Log.d("openprojectView", "openprojectView " + openprojectView + "sound " + sound);
    recordSound();

}
```

and refer to Layout with: `TextView soundUmrandung = (TextView) openprojectView.findViewById(R.id.soundumrandungtextview);`. The result is no error anymore, but it shows a new blank view. When I close the new blank view I see everything but the Buttons lost their clickListener. So I can't record Audio anymore.

The buttons lost their ClickListener too, when I try to open the new class with `new SoundRecord(context)`. It seems to be wrong for me, when I extend the class from Activity, because the Class shouldn't open a new Activity. The Class should only have access to the elements of the parent activity.

So my class now:

> public class SoundRecord {

```
private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = null;
private File soundFile = null;
private String soundFilePath;
private View openprojectView;
//final Context context = this;

public SoundRecord(Context context){

    LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    //setContentView(R.layout.openproject);
    //LayoutInflater layoutinflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    openprojectView = layoutinflater.inflate(R.layout.openproject, null);
    //TextView sound = (TextView) openprojectView.findViewById(R.id.soundumrandungtextview);
    //Log.d("openprojectView", "openprojectView " + openprojectView + "sound " + sound);
    recordSound(context);

}
```

And in OpenProject the class is called by: `new SoundRecord(context);`

Please help me. I really need to split my code into classes.

Comment: How your java code correlates with `R.layout.openproject`?

Comment: have you tried sending the Activity to the 2 Classes after inflation?

Comment: In Java code I need to have access to the Elements of R.layout.openproject (for example arrowLeft).

Comment: Sorry, what do you exactly mean with sending the Activity of the 2 Classes?